# pandas resample with index distance

Tags: pandas

I have a 2D matrix with (MxN) dimensions. M--> time, N--> space.
M has a fixed frequency (every 1s), while N is irregularly spaced.

I want to resample in both M and N, by stacking (averaging)
So I create a pandas dataframe,

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=singal_time.shape[0], freq='s')
dlf=pd.DataFrame(dhi,index=index)
dlf=dlf.resample('10s').mean().values
```

So the data are re-sampled in time.

The N dimensions is dictated by a vector dis[Mx1] where I have distance of each column. That has irregularly spacing, is about 10cm, but not constant.

My idea to to make a new dataframe

```
dlf=pd.Dataframe(dlf.T,index=dis)
```

My how can I resample it say every 1 m with average value?

In short

```
dlf=np.random.rand(1000,2000)
length_signal=dlf.shape[0]
dt=1
singal_length_time=dt*length_signal
singal_time=np.arange(0,singal_length_time,dt)

space_dim=m=np.arange(0,200,0.1)
```

If i resample every 10 lines and 10 rows, the new dlf should be (100,200) size

Comment: Can you create some mock data and expected output?

Comment: I do not thing is usefull, but I will give it a try, any random data would do it.